# mutiple <select> elements validation makes submission of form complicated

Tags: javascript, html

The sample form I created contains only 3 `<select>` items because I'm practicing form validation with the birthdate of the user. If even one of the 3 `<select>` items has no value, the form is supposed to `preventDefault()`; otherwise it would `return true`.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="month" id="month">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
  </select>
  <select name="day" id="day">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="">2000</option>
    <option value="">2001</option>
    <option value="">2002</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In my javascript file, I had two options but both failed to execute successfully.

Option 1

```
function validate(e) {
  var selectItems = document.querySelectorAll('select');

  selectItems.forEach(function(item) {
    if(!item.value) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  })
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

Option 2

```
function validate(e) {
  var month = document.querySelector('#month');
  var day = document.querySelector('#day');
  var year = document.querySelector('#year');

  if(!month.value && !day.value && !year.value) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

In option 1, the problem I had was, though the three  items are already complete, the form still doesn't return true.

In option 2, if one of the three  items already has a value while the other two have no value and you submit the form, it returns true.

How should I make this correct?

Comment: What happens if in Option 2 you use or instead of and? That way if any of them are not true then your code executes.

Comment: @JCooke doesn't return true even if you complete the three selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
function validate(e) {
  var selectItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('select'));

  if (selectItems.some(item => !item.value)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="month" id="month">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
  </select>
  <select name="day" id="day">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```